# How to get store certificate for Win phone 8.1 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows-phone, windows-8.1-universal

i have a question about certificate for windows phone 8.1 Universal app.
I passed these steps but certificate wasn't appeare in project:

1. I open it in Visual Studio 2015.
2. Right click project and choose Store=>Associate app with store
3. I log in my microsoft developer account and choose app from the list
4. I checke information about Publisher, Package and so on and press next

After these steps Package.StoreAssociation.xml is created, but AppName_StoreKey.pfx isn't.

Please, help me. What should I do to get AppName_StoreKey.pfx certificate.
(I don't need test certificate).

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you after "AppName_StoreKey.pfx"? Or do you need a [thin metal ruler](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/11/03/a-parable/)?

Comment: To build release package for windows store I need to get StoreKey.pfx file to sign my package. If package signed by test key it can't be uploaded to store.

Comment: You don't need a AppName_StoreKey.pfx to upload your package. My Phone 8.1 project doesn't contain any .pfx files and I've never had any issues to upload to the store. Okay, I use a MSBuild.exe (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) to create the package; but I don't see why .pfx would be stoping you. Can you please add the exact upload error message to your question.

Answer (score 2):

For my experience, only Windows 8.1 app project will contain a TemporaryKey.pfx file. If you create a universal Windows 8.1 app, it will include an AppName.**Windows**_TemporaryKey.pfx file under the Windows 8.1 project but not Windows Phone 8.1. This should also apply to the _StoreKey.pfx.

But it won't make effect on your package submission. Just make sure you have associated your app with the Store, the identity info will be aligned automatically. You can still manage to upload your package:
[image] 
**Updated**:

Also, you can check the two Windows universal 8.1 package manifests in designer.

The Windows 8.1 package manifest have the choose certificate option while Windows phone 8.1 does not:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I hope my app will pass windows store. I knew that windows phone 10 should have StoreKey.pfx that is why I thought windows phone 8.1 should have it too.

Comment: UWP app combines the two projects into one and it will have only one package. So it can be different since Windows phone 8.1 package manifest even doesn't contain the "Choose Certificate" option while Windows 8.1 include it. You can check my updated answer. However, it won't affect your submission as long as you associate your app with the Dev Center app name to create your package. The association has changed the package's publisher and other identity info. For WP 8.1, I never get the .pfx file. Perhaps it's just different since it even doesn't include the "Choose Certificate" option.