# Visual Studio 2015 Missing the Choose Certificate in the appmanifest Package

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, certificate

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app using Xamarin Forms inside of Visual Studio 2015.  I cannot seem to sign the app. I do not have a "Choose Certificate" button on the Package tab of the appxmanifest file like all of the articles I have read say I should.

I ultimately just need to upload the appx package to my company's Azure Intune. I can generate the appx package and I can upload it but it fails with the error "no signature in the subject". From my research, I believe this means it is not signed. However, other articles indicate that by right-clicking on the project > Store > Create App Package > Yes (to deploy to store as I do have a developer account) that this should automatically sign the package. The error I get in the Windows event viewer is that the Publisher in the appxmanifest does not match the publisher of the signing certificate. I can see what each publisher values are, I just can't seem to change them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to upload your package to your company's Azure Intune, you could create a certificate by yourself to sign your appx package.

See [create a self signed certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-certificate-package-signing#create-a-self-signed-certificate) and [Sign an app package using SignTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/sign-app-package-using-signtool).

To publish your app to the Windows Store, you need to associate your app with an existing app name in Dev Center (or you can reserve a new one). The association will automatically align all the app identity info. The Windows Phone 8.1 project does not have the "Choose Certificate" button and it even doesn't include the test certificate in the project. But after association, you could create your appx package and upload it in Dashboard as usual.

You might refer to my response in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224132/how-to-get-store-certificate-for-win-phone-8-1-app) as well.

Comment: I followed your two links and read the information in your post. This led me down the right path. What I ended up doing was using my Publisher ID value from my Windows Dev Center account as the publisher value in the app manifest and self-signed cert.  This worked. Thanks so much for pointing me down the right path!

Comment: Also, the above only works if the Windows phone is in developer mode. You have to go into settings, search for "For Developer" and check the "Developer Mode" option.  I'm sure if we had an actual company signed cert, then we would do the "Sideload" option but with a self-signed cert, I had to do a "Developer Mode".